# JavaScript: Good Plugins for Scrolling elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-tools

The site I'm working on has a div with some items (a feed with several stories) that I want to be scrollable inline without using the default browser scrollbar.

I traversed and crawled the web and found exactly zero plugins that will help me solve this problem.

My main problem with things like jQuery Tools Scrollable is that it totally freaks out on mouse scroll (and even more on trackpad scroll) and there is no way to configure the scrolling animation of a mouse scroll.

My question is:

- Is there a way to change the speed of the mouse/trackpad scroll in jQuery Tools?

OR

- Is there a decent plugin that helps me do this or do I really have to write it myself?